# UWP:- UI freezes/lags in a grid view of media player element

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've a grid view containing media player elements and I'm getting video frames for each user encoded in I420 format from mixed reality webrtc.
I'm following the exact steps in https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/cs/helloworld-cs-mediatracks-uwp.html
to make the video frames render in MediaPlayerElement. This works well if the number of media player elements in the grid view is 12-13. When it crosses, 14-16, we are seeing
lags/freezes in the UI (all user actions are getting slow and resizing taking a hit affecting the user experience).

Went through this msdn documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer) and tried
a) Use MediaPlayerSurface to render video to a Windows.UI.Composition surface
b) Using Media player in frame server mode. But, didn't work

Any pointers on what I'm missing or directions ?

```
        <GridView
            x:Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Margin="0,0,5,0"
            Padding="0,0,0,8"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="center"
            x:Load="True"
            IsItemClickEnabled="False"
            ItemContainerTransitions="{x:Null}"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Users, Mode=OneWay}"
            RotationTransition="{x:Null}"
            ScaleTransition="{x:Null}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            Transitions="{x:Null}"
            TranslationTransition="{x:Null}">
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,0,0" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ParticipantViewPanels:AdaptiveGridPanel x:Name="panel" Loaded="CustomPanel_Loaded" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MediaPlayerElement
                x:Name="VideoPlayerElement"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                AutoPlay="True"
                Background="Black"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                CornerRadius="5"                    
                Opacity="0.8"
                RotationTransition="{x:Null}"
                ScaleTransition="{x:Null}"
                Transitions="{x:Null}"
                TranslationTransition="{x:Null}"
                Visibility="Visible" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

**EDITS:-**

On running a performance profiler (Application timeline), I see time is being spent by the xaml runtime.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the memory use of your app in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, it was clocking around 600 MB and CPU usage was 35-40%. This was when grid view had 16 media player elements playing remote videos.

Comment: Just a guess, but does turning off `CornerRadius` make it any faster?

Comment: Nope. Just tried in my end and that didn’t help either. But just curious to know how does turning off the corner radius can help in this case ?

Comment: How is the media player getting the data?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Any thoughts or suggestions on this?